# Avoid neopixel power on USB

Tags: arduino, power-supply, mosfet, usb

I am designing a lamp based on  neopixel leds and arduino. I'm designing the badge on Eagle and I've noticed a problem. I have noticed that with the consumption of the LEDs (5A) when the user tries to program the lamp ​Will try to turn on the leds of the usb and can be damaged. How can I make the lamp only turn on when the Power supply is connected and if the USB is not alone?

I have thought of a system based on MOSFET

Comment: I'd suggest you simply add a jumper that disconnects (I assume) your PWM signal for the LEDS. Pull out the jumper when programming via USB.

Comment: Is a pretty good option but I thought more of something automatic. Thank you!

Comment: Put a diode on the supply line of the micro?

Comment: @uint128_t, that's a really viable option, a single Schottky from the main 5 V tracks to the processor and the USB/serial chip. The only care that needs to be taken is that when running on the main supply 5 V, the processor will be on less voltage, so care must be taken with pullups (especially those required for programming), and drive levels to FET switches.

Comment: Best option in terms of usability would be: have the MCU detect whether power is coming from USB or VIN. If USB, lower Neopixel brightness by ~90% (500mA max), so user can still debug/preview. If Vin (not USB), then set Neopixels at 100% of what was configured.

Comment: @JackCreasey But the MCU will not turn on with less than 5v

Comment: @WesleyLee detect It with a current sensor?

Comment: No, you can feed the 5V inputs into I/Os. Whichever I/O is high is the power source your user is getting.

Comment: @WesleyLee ok its a good option, and another solution using a MOSFET?

Comment: I don't get what you mean. What do you want to use the mosfet for?

Comment: @WesleyLee a MOSFET for switching the power supply between the USB port  and the leds

Comment: You don't need to switch, just detect which one is being used and decide the brightness based on it.

Comment: @WesleyLee And how can I do to protect that part of the code? As the user can reprogram it and if you change that part you can burn it. that's the problem

Comment: Well, you can't protect that in code. If I stick a fork in my power outlet I could die. There are limits to where you can try to make things "user-friendly". I'd argue that if someone is writing software for your hardware he should know that. BUT, you can put a fuse. Either a one time fuse or a resettable one.

Comment: And something like this? http://imgur.com/a/k8l2F

Comment: Simplest solution would be to make your device self powered - either *ignore* the USB VBUS, or just look at it (most likely via a divider) to tell if a host is trying to talk to you, but only draw operational power from your usual supply, never VBUS.

Comment: @ChrisStratton had not thought of that. It's fantastic thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a schottky diode, a large (1Mohm recommended) resistor to drain diode leakage to GND, and an N-channel FET to detect power supply power, and cut off all the LEDs any time the power supply isn't providing voltage.

Something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVIaA2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>